# How to get month name from month number

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

```
month=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

This array I am getting from server. How to get Month Name?

Till now  I tried this:

```
var populateChartData = function (data) {
    var getMonth = [];
    var getProfit = [];
    $scope.chartTitle = 'Year :' + moment().year();
    data.forEach(function (obj) {
        console.log(obj.month);
        getMonth.push(moment().month(obj.month).format('MMM'));
    });
    console.log(getMonth);
};
```

but in console I'm getting

```
["Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct"]
```

I should get like this

```
["Jan","Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did as below

```
       var populateChartData = function (data) {
        var getMonth = [];
        var getProfit = [];

        data.forEach(function (obj) {

            getMonth.push(moment().month(obj.month-1).format('MMM'));
        });
        console.log(getMonth);
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

you could just create your own filter like this: otherwise, pass the index into one function and get Month Name

```
myApp.filter('monthName', [function() {
    return function (monthNumber) { //1 = January
        var monthNames = [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
            'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ];
        return monthNames[monthNumber - 1];
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try from 0 index in the month array.or while iterating that array put -1 for that value.

Answer (score 1):

0 corresponds to January, 1 to February and so on (from 0 to 11). It is done in such way because indexing usually starts from 0. Hence from programming point of view 0 is a good choice for January

Answer (score 1):

In momentjs month number starts from 0.
You can see this documentation from moment

[momentjs month](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/)